# Getting this error - 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

Hello hope some one helps me on this challenge.
Getting this error - 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

I'm trying to get the posts of the users that I follow, in the models I used GenericForeignKey

the error is pointing at the first statement .  - (**{% for post in posts_list %}**)

```
{% for post in posts_list %}
{{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPostsBoardView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Context = {} 
        # the users i'm following
        im_following = self.request.user.profile.following.all() 

        query_set = Post.objects.filter(User__name__contains=im_following)

        Context["posts_list"] = query_set


        return render(request,"posts/user/user_board.html", Context)
```

**posts/models.py**

```
class Userposts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="User")
    val_obj = GenericRelation(Post, object_id_field="object_id",
                          related_query_name="User")
```

**userprofiles/models.py**

```
class Userprofiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="follow")


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.following.all().count())
```

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in
>   inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _legacy_get_response
>     249.             response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in
>   dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\wahab\Desktop\site1\ostra\ostrakodecommerce\posts\views.py"
>   in get
>     75.             return render(request,"posts/user/user_board.html", Context)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py"
>   in render
>     30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in
>   render_to_string
>     68.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
>   in render
>     66.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     207.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in
>   render
>     216.                 return template.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     209.                 return self._render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in
>   render_annotated
>     957.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in
>   render
>     173.             len_values = len(values)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in **len**
>     232.         self._fetch_all()
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   _fetch_all
>     1105.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   **iter**
>     53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   execute_sql
>     863.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   as_sql
>     420.             where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   compile
>     373.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in
>   as_sql
>     79.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in
>   compile
>     373.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in
>   as_sql
>     170.         rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in
>   process_rhs
>     433.             params[0] = "%%%s%%" % connection.ops.prep_for_like_query(params[0])
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /profile/-.1/public_board Exception
>   Value: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Can you show how you are supplying the `posts_list`?

Comment: Could you also post the full traceback?

Comment: Show the view rendering posts_list please.

Comment: post the full traceback

Comment: What is "Context" here? It doesn't seem to be defined within your view.

Comment: Its there, as Context = {}, on top of the files

Comment: Post your `urls.py`

Answer (score 1):

Use `__in` instead of `__contains`.

```
im_following = self.request.user.profile.following.all().values_list('username', flat=True) 
query_set = Post.objects.filter(User__name__in=im_following)
```

Comment: @Alasdir - I have used that before and it runs well (without errors) but doesn't display the posts from the users I follow

Comment: I think the issue is in this file ** posts/models.py **

Comment: `im_following` is a queryset of users. Try `User__in` instead of `User__name__in`.

Comment: ValueError      Cannot use QuerySet for "User": Use a QuerySet for "Userposts".

Comment: Try using `values_list` to create a list of `usernames`. Storing the user as a `CharField` is a surprising choice. Why not use a foreign key?

Comment: Hello, you editing produces a black post. not the posts of the user that I follow

Comment: Its working well now, it was my mistake, you last edit has saved my nights